# Identify this Giant Escape

Tags: identify-this-bike

Can someone identify this Giant Escape's (r) version? been planning to restore this bike but i haven't known the model yet.[image: giantescape]

Comment: How would knowing the exact details of the model help your restoration?  It's a Giant Escape with V brakes and a triple chainset.  Needs some parts (saddle, seatpost, pedals) and may need new rubber parts and chain depending on wear and storage.

Comment: @Criggie thanks for the comment, +1!

Answer (score 1):

Did some research bout it and found out that this is a Giant Escape R3 2013.